# provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 Error in Visual Studio and MsSql

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently making a cafe management system and I'm having this issue with a bunch of buttons and textboxes. I really need help with this situation, appreciated the helpers.

My string:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "data source =DESKTOP-TN9HLSG\\SQLEXPRESS;database = kafe; integrated security =True";
        return con;
```

and the error comes to `cmdOpen();` sentence:

```
    public void setData(String query)
    {
        SqlConnection con = getConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open(); (here)
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

and this is the error message when i try to open the project

[External Code]
KafeUygulamasi.function.setData(string) / function.cs    KafeUygulamasi.TumKullaniciIslemleri.KD_UrunEkle.btnUrunEkle1_Click(object, System.EventArgs) / KD_UrunEkle.cs
[External Code]
KafeUygulamasi.Program.Main() / Program.cs

this is the full code img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lMaf.jpg

Comment: What is the message of error?

Comment: This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    CMS.Function.setData(string) in Function.cs
    CMS.AllUserControls.UC_AddItems.btnAddItem_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in UC_AddItems.cs
    [External Code]
    CMS.Program.Main() in Program.cs

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72474949/edit) your question to include the full exception message - as text, not screen shot(s). Full exception messages, including stack traces, often reveal the actual nature of the problem such as _Error Locating Server/Instance Specified_ pointing to SQL Browser service-related issues trying to resolve instance names.